# why is multi GPU tensorflow retraining not working

Tags: tensorflow

I have been training my tensorflow retraining algorithm using a single GTX Titan and it works just fine, but when I try to use multiple gpus in the flower of retraining example it does not work and seems to only utilize one GPU when I run it in Nvidia SMI.

Why is this happening as it does work with multiple gpus when retraining at Inception model from scratch but not during retraining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow's flower retraining example does not work with multiple GPUs at all, even if you set `--num_gpus` > 1.  It should support a single GPU as you noted.

The model needs to be modified to utilize multiple GPUs in parallel. Unfortunately, a single TensorFlow operation like the flower retraining example can't automatically be split over multiple GPUs at this time.

Comment: Can you provide example of how to make it GPU mp?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is way beyond the scope of a SO comment/answer, but there are some good starting points if you go to the TensorFlow multi-GPU basics tutorial and examine their source code.